# How to install WordPress locally to be viewed externally via static ip

Tags: wordpress, static, installation, ip, xampp

i wanna install a WordPress locally on xampp , to be viewed and edited externally through the internet via static ip , i have been trying it but keep running into problems , can someone help me through a number of steps that i can accomplish that , without having any problems in the future , there is bits and pieces everywhere but no specific set of instructions , on how to do that , please can someone help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

(This first step is the easy part, just software and small interaction.)

1. Install Wordpress with xampp or another, this PC will need to be on as a normal server in order to access local or by Internet -> http://es.wikihow.com/instalar-Wordpress-en-XAMPP

(Hardware part)

1. After tested localhost/wp (or any name you like) you need to forward the port 80 of the pc with has WP to the router that has visible IP (I'm sharing some samples with most known brands):

   - portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/AirLive/WL-1500R/Zmodo_M6304.htm
   - www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/tp-link-router-port-forwarding/
   - www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/ (THIS HAS GOOD IMAGES TO UNDERSTAND BETTER)
2. You won't be able to access router config by Internet because the router will redirect you to the WP "server". To check the public IP just go to: http://www.whatismyip.com/
3. Share the IP with a friend or connect with 3G/4G on phone, put it on browser and your server will be ready to use on Internet.

5 (optional) you can install dynamic DNS to fix a name to your local server, because usually the Internet provider changes the IP numbers, and if you use it some day you won't be able to connect because your router would be using another IP (example: www.noip.com/ )

I hope you find this info useful. Regards

Comment: Thank you for answering , i did all that i installed it locally using xampp , forwarded the port on my router , when i try to access it over the internet , i can't see the pictures on my wordpress site , and i can't access my wp-admin page at all , it gives me an error 404 that it can't be found

Comment: please enable mod-rewrite on apache and update all fields of your DB according to your new URL